# JQuery UI Dialog: Dynamic OnClick Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, modal-dialog, onclicklistener

How to start an OnClick event for an UI Dialog in JQuery dynamically ?

Every SVG-rect element (1,2,...,1000) should be able to open this dialog, while a parameter or ID should be submitted as well to identify which svg was clicked.

The relevant JS code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#request_1" )
        .click(function() {
            createForm();
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );       
    });
/*....*/
};
```

The relevant HTML Code looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="720" height="125">
    <rect id="request_1" x="180.5" y="15" width="39" height="15">
    </rect>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" width="720" height="125">
    <rect id="request_2" x="180.5" y="15" width="39" height="15">
    </rect>
</svg>

/*[...]*/

<svg version="1.1" width="720" height="125">
    <rect id="request_1000" x="180.5" y="15" width="39" height="15">
    </rect>
</svg>
```

The problem comes from this example where you can find the full source code: 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Imagine you would have 1000 different buttons.

Any idea?
I guess using a simple onClick would be a solution, but how to start the .click(function()) then?

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either bind `click` to `rect` or add a class to `rect` and bind `click` event to the class.

```
$( "rect" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

If it is a dynamically added element, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', 'rect', function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Fdc6b/1/

Comment: Thank you!! This works fine!
Do you have any idea how to submit any parameter? Such as the indivdual ID of the individual RECT-element?

Comment: What do you mean by "submit"? What element would you like to populate?  To get the `id`, use in either example, `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: Once I click on the rect with id=1000, my JS code should be able to read this value. Up to this id, specific data should get loaded, e.g. a name. So I need to know, which rect was clicked.

Comment: Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to find info about selected element.  To get the element's `id`, use `$(this).attr('id')`.  [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is also something to look into. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

if you want to add dynamic elements, use live function to attache events for new elements like this :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#request_1" ).live('click',function() {
            createForm();
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );       
    });
/*....*/
};
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9+, you should be using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.